# Почему вместо картинки прогружается квадрат

Tags: javascript, reactjs, img, print

При нажатии на печать картинка правильно рендерится только со второго раза, я использую для печати:

```
window.print()
```

Вот что в src у img в момент отрисовки. Хотел бы узнать причину бага.
[image: картинка]

[image: Первое нажатие на печать]

[image: Второе нажатие на печать]